# Ausdrucksstarkes deutsches Wort oder Wortgebilde für "Big Data"?

Tags: english-to-german

Nur aus Interesse, weiß jemand oder hat jemand eine Idee für ein gutes Wort für "Big Data"?

Alle Synonyme, durch die ich bis jetzt geblättert habe, sind etwas platt. Vielleicht "Endlos Daten" war meine beste Idee, aber ich bin sicher, dass es besser geht.

Comment: Bleib bei [Big Data](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Data). Auf Gedeih und Verderb eine Übersetzung zu suchen, scheint mir bei aller Liebe zur Vermeidung unnötiger Anglizismen unnötig.

Comment: Ich finde, CamelCase macht sich in deutschen Texten auch nicht besonders gut.

Comment: @PMF Das heißt immer noch camelCase bitte..

Comment: @Vogel612: Ich glaube jetzt nicht, dass das hier die richtige Plattform für einen Disput über Namenskonventionen von Programmiersprachen ist ;-)

Comment: Mir geht's nicht wirklich um den Fachbegriff. Ich moechte nur ein Projekt unter Freunden benennen; daher die Frage mehr aus Neugierde heraus.

Comment: Und welche Synonyme waren das - nicht dass wir die jetzt nach und nach selbst hervorbringen.

Comment: Danke fuer alle Antworten. Ist irgendwie schwierig, eine "richtige" Antwort zu bestimmen. Ich hab jetzt mal das Datengebirge gewaehlt, weil es mir persoenlich am Besten zusagt. Danke aber an alle Teilnehmenden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datenhalde, Datenberg, Datengebirge.

Comment: `Halde` klingt nach einer achtlosen und nicht besonders sicheren Art der Lagerung (ein offener Lagerplatz ohne Dach), und wegen der Ähnlichkeit zu `Müllhalde` würde wohl auch eine gewisse Nutzlosigkeit der angelegten Sammlung mitschwingen.

Comment: Dann doch schon eher "*Datenberg*".

Comment: "Datengebirge" finde ich ganz gut :)

Comment: @Hulk: Das ist aber ein unzulässiger Schluss. Eine Müllhalde ist ja eine sehr spezielle Halde (nicht etwas ähnliches). Die Nutzlosigkeit folgert aber einzig aus dem Müllanteil, den Du als Spezialisierung hinzufügst. So wie ein Eimer auch Austern beherbergen kann, ungeachtet aller Mülleimer, die diesem in seiner eimerhaftigkeit ähnlich sind, so gibt es auch Rohstoffhalden mit Neodymerz oder Antrazit. Ob die gesichert sind oder nicht ist eine andere Frage. Dass Vergleiche und Metaphern nur begrenzt tragen ist nix neues.

Comment: @userunknown I think he meant the "similarity" due to both words contain `Halde` which, IMO, is amongst populace mostly known from or associated with the word `Müllhalde`

Comment: @userunknown, @embert indeed - the intention of my comment was to point out that `Halde` is rarely used (outside of logistics or storage of raw materials) in any other context than disposal of waste. It may therefore have some negative connotation if the term stands by itself (in a headline, as a bullet point in a presentation). It may be fine as a technical term if it is clear from context that `data` is considered a valuable raw material waiting to be refined into something more sophisticated.

Comment: @Hulk: Die Floskel von den "negative connotations" kann ich nicht mehr hören, denn sie ist ein einfältig und primitiv. Man hat schließlich Müllhalden, weil man sie braucht - offenbar lösen sie ein Problem. Für den Betreiber sichern sie sein wirtschaftliches Einkommen. Hören wir doch auf so zu tun als ob die Welt für alle gleich sein müsste und sich in ein Schwarz/Weiß-Schema unterteilen ließe, und als ob das hier zu irgendwelchen Erkenntnissen führen könnte. Dass Du meinst die Häufigkeit mit der Du von Müll- im Ggs. zu anderen Halden sprichst wäre von Relevanz ist das nächste Ärgernis.

Comment: @Hulk: Zu allem Überfluss ist es auch noch so, dass gerade die Müllhalde ein hervorragendes Bild abgibt, denn Glas, Plastik, Staub, Papier ist in kleinen Mengen eine Belastung, in Großen Mengen und sortiert wird es wertvoll, was eben prächtig auf die Datensammelei passt.

Comment: @userunknown Ich stimme dir in der Sache zu. Der Bergriff `Halde` wie er in der Schüttgutlogistik verwendet wird, ist durchaus treffend als Metapher für die Lagerung einer großen Menge von unsortierten Daten. Je nach Zielgruppe kann Erklärungsbedarf entstehen, was bei neuen Begriffen aber nicht ungewöhnlich ist. Meine Bedenken waren eher emotionaler und damit rein subjektiver Natur.

Answer (score 9):

Eine mögliche Übersetzung wäre `große Datenmengen`.

Aber da [Big Data](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Data) inzwischen ein etablierter Fachbegriff ist, rate ich von einer Übersetzung ab und würde `Big Data`verwenden.

Eine etwas informale Möglichkeit wäre der `Datenhaufen`, dazu hat es [bei Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=datenhaufen) auch schon einige Treffer. Den Fachbegriff `Big Data` würde ich als `Datenhaufenanalyse` übersetzen (Nach meinem Verständnis ist Big Data nicht nur große Datenmengen sondern die Fähigkeit diese großen Daetenmengen zu verarbeiten).

Comment: Siehe Kommentar zur Frage. Ich finde "grosse Datenmengen" leider ein wenig einfallslos :(

Comment: Naja, "big data" ist auch nicht gerade einfallsreicher...

Comment: `Große Daten` oder `Riesige Daten` klingt für mich griffiger als `große Datenmengen`.

Comment: Aber `Große Daten` würde bedeuten, dass `groß`eine Eigenschaft der `Daten` ist, während mit `Big Data` doch die Sammlung und Verarbeitung großer `Mengen`von Daten gemeint ist.

Comment: `Große Datenmengen` fassen wesentliche Aspekte nicht: Die Vernetzung der Daten, ihr Potential zur Monetarisierung. `Datenhaufenanalyse` suggeriert wiederum, daß die Daten unstrukturiert seien - meistens sind sie zumindest teilstrukturiert, andernfalls würde man eher von `Data Mining` sprechen. Da `Datenhaufen` kein stehender Begriff im datentechnischen Wortfeld ist, besteht zudem im Prinzip eine  Verwechslungsgefahr mit dem `data heap`, einer Datenstruktur im programmiertechnischen Sinn.

Answer (score 8):

Am treffendsten ist wohl noch *Massendaten*. Allerdings würde ich *Big Data* als Anglizismus verwenden, weil es sich so in der IT-Welt etabliert hat.

Answer (score 2):

Um dem bereits Gesagten noch ein weiteres hinzuzufügen:

> Daten**meer**

Alles was sehr groß ist, kann man mittels entsprechender Komposita ausdrücken:

- **-halde:** nutzlose unsortierte Menge
- **-berg:** große Menge, schwer bezwingbar
- **-gebirge:** Steigerung zu -berg.
- **-meer:** annähernd unendliche, nicht fassbare Menge
- **-riese:** einzelnes sehr großes, aber noch zu ermessendes Gebilde
- **-strom:** eine große Menge, die sich von einem Ort zum anderen bewegt
- **-masse:** eine große, aber eher statische Menge
- **-see:** überschaubare, aber schwer zu erfassende große Menge
- ...

Welches Kompositum am geeignetsten ist, ist subjektiv und hängt auch ein wenig von der Wirkung ab, die man erzielen möchte.

Comment: Gute Zusammenfassung.

Answer (score -1):

Big Data, data mining und big brother sind wohl ziemlich verwandt.

1. Große Mengen Daten werden automatisch verarbeitet
2. von ganz großen Anbietern google, NSA etc. (die damit auch spionieren)
3. nimmt Bezug auf Orwells Roman "1984"

hm, schwierig, das alles mit einem deutschen Begriff auszudrücken. Vor allem wird es ziemlich sicher ein weit längeres Wort als im Englischen.

"großangelegte Datenverarbeitung in der/in einer schlimmeren Dimension von/als Orwells '1984'"

wäre ein Vorschlag. Ich würde es einmal so erklären und dann sagen: "Abgekürzt: Big data" :-D

Comment: Zwischen `Big Data` und `Data Mining` besteht ein wesentlicher Unterschied: Letzteres bezeichnet die Extraktion 'wertvoller' Information aus unstrukturierten Daten (vereinfacht: aus natürlichsprachlichem Fließtext). `Big Data` hingegen beschäftigt sich mit (teil-)strukturierten Datenmengen. Auch die Verbindung mit 'big brother' scheint mir eher schwach, da sie personenbezogene Daten voraussetzt. Damit wären fast alle wissenschaftlichen `Big Data`-Anwendungen ausgegrenzt.

Comment: Richtigstellung zu `Data Mining`: Damit bezeichnet man auch die Suche nach verborgenen Zusammenhängen in strukturierten Daten, also in z.B. in relationalen Datenbanken (Beispiel Supermarkt: Welche Produkte werden von Kunden besonders häufig gemeinsam gekauft?) Ich habe selbst mehrere Jahre lang als Datenmanager bei einer Bank gearbeitet, mitgeholfen das »Data Ware House« dieser Bank aufzubauen, und dann in diesem DWH mittels »Data Mining« nach solchen verborgenen Zusammenhängen gesucht.

Answer (score -2):

Komplexdatenverarbeitung Oder noch ein schönes zusammengesetztes Substantiv Elektronischekomplexdatenverarbeitungsanlage ;)

Big Data heisst es ist 
a. viel
b. zusammenhängend
c. komplex 
Komplex = viel
Komplex = zusammenhängend
Komplex = strukturiert

Komplex = Big
Daten = Data
Komplexdaten
Und wie jemand anderes oben schon anbrachte. Es geht darum die zu verarbeiten.
Daher
Komplexdatenverarbeitungsalgorithmusforschungsinstitutssteuerbescheidzustellung

Deutsch macht Spaß!